# Which style would be better when two functions have the same content in c/c++?

Tags: c++, coding-style

Assume that you have a base class:

```
class base  
{  
public:  
  virtual void OnConnect() = 0;  
  virtual void OnDisonnect() = 0;  

  // Other functions ...  
};
```

Several classes inherit from base, and most of them have different implementation for these two functions. However, one of these derived classes has the same content and I was wondering which of the following style would be better and why:

(A) Leave the duplicate code in both functions

```
void derived::OnConnect(const char* err)
{  
    /*  
     * 3~5 lines of code in this function with a block of comment.
     */
}

void derived::OnDisconnect(const char* err)
{  
    /*  
     * 3~5 lines of code in this function with a block of comment.
     */
}
```

(B) Delegate one to the other

```
void derived::OnConnect(const char* err)
{  
    /*  
     * 3~5 lines of code in this function with a block of comment.
     */
}

void derived::OnDisconnect(const char* err)
{  
    // Same as OnConnect()
    OnConnect(err);
}
```

(C) Define another function and call that function in OnConnect/OnDisconnect

```
static func(const char* err)
{
    /*  
     * 3~5 lines of code in this function with a block of comment.
     */
}

void derived::OnConnect(const char* err)
{  
    func(err);
}

void derived::OnDisconnect(const char* err)
{  
    func(err);
}
```

Which one would be better?

Comment: Note: this is not `c`, so you don't need that tag. And there is no `c/c++` language.

Comment: I'd go for option (C), especially if the functions name tells someone reading the code what it actually does.

Comment: Why is `func` not a class method in option C?

Comment: I would go for alternative C, since it expresses the intent in the clearest way (i.e. connection and disconnection are different events, but they need to perform the same action) and you'll be prepared for the extrememly likely event that you want to do something in one that you don't want to do in the other.

Comment: Nabla is right.  It should be a private member function.

Comment: ok, sorry for taking a bad example(polymorphism). The problem I'd like to ask is which style would be better when two functions have dup code. It can be seen in any language.

Comment: @Nabla Yes it could be a private member function.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is nothing in the two function interfaces that suggests one should have anything to do with the other, I think we can safely rule out option B.

Personnally I'd go for option C.

Answer (score 0):

Never cut and paste code, or at least **avoid** it *as much as possible*.
Cut & past quickly becomes unmaintainable.  So forget option (A).

I would go for solution (C) because in (B) because it makes logically more sense to me : A disconnect function that calls a connection ?

Comment: The question was ironic, sorry if that was not clear : definitively I would go for (C).